# How to connect an ASP.Net Core MVC2 project to a remote database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

After developing ASP.Net web applications for as long as I care to remember, I've finally got some time to teach myself ASP.Net core MVC2 with EF (I'm using VS 2017 by the way).  I've got a fair number of databases sitting on a remote server and I would like to get a project to connect to one of them, and this is where I run into troubles.  There's a few good tutorials about connecting to an existing database, but they all connect to a local database.
I'm probably being stupid and not seeing the obvious, but I could use some help on this.  Does anyone know of a good tutorial that will teach me how to connect my project to a remote database?
It used to be so easy in C# desktop or ASP.Net web apps with entity framework, I just built the database, connected it to my project, and away it went. I want to connect an ASP.Net Core MVC app to a remote database using EF core.

I'm sorry, after reading the comments I should have put in what code was failing and where.  Here it is now. (please excuse me, I've been banging my head on this for for over a week now and I'm getting frustrated).
Here's my Startup.cs file, with the configure services method I use to call the database:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration["Data:ConnStringName:ConnectionString"]));
            services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, EFProductRepository>();
            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

and here's the contents of my App.JSON file which sets the connection string:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "ConnStringName": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server= (Name of my remote server)\\SqlExpress;Database=databaseName;id=UserName;password=password:Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultsSets=true"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: whats your question? you want to connect db from winform or web app?

Comment: All you need to change is data source in the connection string. Instead local database server name you need to put remote databse server or IP. Did you try that?

Comment: Yep, i've tried that, it just thumbs it's nose at me.  I've tried using connection strings from other projects, but no joy at all.

Comment: What exactly happens when you put proper values in the connection string ? You need to share the code which you think is the issue. Where are you keeping the connection string ?

Comment: This question is both unclear and overly broad.  There isn't any concrete information here, no error messages, and nothing to go on that would tell us what you have tried, much less what problems the techniques you have tried actually cause.

Comment: Please excuse me, I've edited the original query to include the code where I think it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

the question is broad/no error message , but from what i understood , try to implement the below in your startup file (fill in your connection string details below)

```
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
     {
        app.UseDataEngineProviders().AddDataEngine("DB Name", @"Data Source=;Provider=;Initial Catalog=", "table name");

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();
     }
```

there are also many data sourse types available from the method UseDataEngineProviders that you can use .